# How to use the polynomial function equation to extract coefficients from all segments in all channels using SQL query

Tags: sql, segmentation-fault, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, polynomials

I am looking to query the data for a list of channels from Snowflake using SQL query and then used the polynomial function equation to each segment in each channel. The number of rows for each segment is 100 rows. I tried the SQL query below, but I have received this error:

> Error: invalid identifier 'engine_temperature_1' (line 32) -->

```
AVG(engine_temperature_1) - (SUM(x * CAST(TIME AS FLOAT) * CAST(TIME AS FLOAT)) / SUM(CAST(TIME AS FLOAT) * CAST(TIME AS FLOAT))) - (SUM(x * CAST(TIME AS FLOAT)) / SUM(CAST(TIME AS FLOAT) * CAST(TIME AS FLOAT))) AS c
```

This is the query:

```
WITH C1 AS (
SELECT
    SERIAL_NUMBER,
    EVENT_DATE,
    EVENT_TS AS TIME,
    CAST (VIMS:_engine_speed AS FLOAT) AS ENGSPD,
    CAST (VIMS:_engine_load AS FLOAT) AS Engine_load,
    CAST (VIMS:_engine_temperature_1 AS FLOAT) AS engine_temperature_1,
    CAST (VIMS:_engine_temperature_2) AS engine_temperature_2,
    CAST (VIMS:_engine_temperature_3 AS FLOAT) AS engine_temperature_3,
    CAST (VIMS:_engine_temperature_4 AS FLOAT) AS engine_temperature_4,
    FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EVENT_TS) - 1) / 100) + 1 AS 
segment_id
FROM "HELIOS_TDH_VIMS_PROD_DB"."BASE"."DATA_LOGGER"
WHERE
    SERIAL_NUMBER in ('KSN00205')
    AND EVENT_DATE = '2022-11-18'
ORDER BY
    SERIAL_NUMBER, EVENT_TS
)
SELECT C1.TIME,
    C1.segment_id,
    AVG(C1.engine_temperature_1) AS avg_temp,
    AVG(C1.engine_temperature_1) - (a * POWER(AVG(C1.TIME), 2) + b * 
AVG(C1.TIME) + c) AS residual
FROM C1
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT segment_id,
    SUM(x) / COUNT(*) AS a,
    SUM(x * TIME) / SUM(TIME * TIME) AS b,
    AVG(engine_temperature_1) - (SUM(x * CAST(TIME AS FLOAT) * CAST(TIME AS 
FLOAT)) / SUM(CAST(TIME AS FLOAT) * CAST(TIME AS FLOAT))) - (SUM(x * 
CAST(TIME AS FLOAT)) / SUM(CAST(TIME AS FLOAT) * CAST(TIME AS FLOAT))) AS c
FROM (SELECT
    segment_id,
    engine_temperature_1 - AVG(engine_temperature_1) AS x,
    TIME
    FROM C1)
GROUP BY
    segment_id) 
GROUP BY C1.TIME, C1.segment_id
```

What should change in that query to fix the error above.

Comment: You need `C1.engine_temperature_1`.  There's no local column in that query with that name.

Comment: I have this channel in the table on snowflake: CAST (VIMS:_engine_temperature_1 AS FLOAT) AS engine_temperature_1,

Comment: so what I should change in that query?

Comment: Yes, but that's inside the subtable C1.  Outside of the `WITH` parentheses, you have to use the table qualifier.  I told you exactly what to change.  Do it exactly like you did in the second `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because when you pull things from C1 in your CROSS JOIN SUB-SELECT you don't pull it in:

thus:

```
WITH c1 AS (
    SELECT
        serial_number,
        event_date,
        event_ts AS time,
        vims:_engine_speed::float AS ENGSPD,
        vims:_engine_load::float AS Engine_load,
        vims:_engine_temperature_1::float AS engine_temperature_1,
        vims:_engine_temperature_2::float AS engine_temperature_2,
        vims:_engine_temperature_3::float) AS engine_temperature_3,
        vims:_engine_temperature_4::float) AS engine_temperature_4,
        FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY event_ts) - 1) / 100) + 1 AS segment_id
    FROM helios_tdh_vims_prod_db.base.data_logger
    WHERE serial_number in ('KSN00205')
        AND event_date = '2022-11-18'
    ORDER BY serial_number, event_ts
)
SELECT 
    c1.time,
    c1.segment_id,
    AVG(C1.engine_temperature_1) AS avg_temp,
    AVG(C1.engine_temperature_1) - (a * POWER(AVG(C1.TIME), 2) + b * AVG(C1.TIME) + c) AS residual
FROM C1
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 
        segment_id,
        SUM(x) / COUNT(*) AS a,
        SUM(x * TIME) / SUM(TIME * TIME) AS b,
        AVG(engine_temperature_1) - (SUM(x * TIME::float * TIME::float) / SUM(TIME::float * TIME::float)) - (SUM(x * TIME::float) / SUM(TIME::float * TIME::float)) AS c
    FROM (
        SELECT
            segment_id,
            engine_temperature_1 - AVG(engine_temperature_1) AS x,
            engine_temperature_1,
            TIME
        FROM C1
    )
    GROUP BY segment_id
) 
GROUP BY c1.time, c1.segment_id
```

should work. I would be inclined to to the float and squaring once, to make the code more readable. As the optimizer should do this anyways.

```
WITH c1 AS (
    SELECT
        serial_number,
        event_date,
        event_ts AS time,
        vims:_engine_speed::float AS ENGSPD,
        vims:_engine_load::float AS Engine_load,
        vims:_engine_temperature_1::float AS engine_temperature_1,
        vims:_engine_temperature_2::float AS engine_temperature_2,
        vims:_engine_temperature_3::float) AS engine_temperature_3,
        vims:_engine_temperature_4::float) AS engine_temperature_4,
        FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY event_ts) - 1) / 100) + 1 AS segment_id
    FROM helios_tdh_vims_prod_db.base.data_logger
    WHERE serial_number in ('KSN00205')
        AND event_date = '2022-11-18'
    ORDER BY serial_number, event_ts
)
SELECT 
    c1.time,
    c1.segment_id,
    AVG(C1.engine_temperature_1) AS avg_temp,
    AVG(C1.engine_temperature_1) - (a * POWER(AVG(c1.time), 2) + b * AVG(c1.time) + c) AS residual
FROM C1
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 
        segment_id,
        SUM(x) / COUNT(*) AS a,
        SUM(x * time) / SUM(time * time) AS b,
        AVG(engine_temperature_1) - (SUM(x * time_f_sq) / SUM(time_f_sq)) - (SUM(x * time_f) / SUM(time_f_sq)) AS c
    FROM (
        SELECT
            segment_id,
            engine_temperature_1 - AVG(engine_temperature_1) AS x,
            engine_temperature_1,
            time,
            time * time as time_sq,
            time::float as time_f,
            time_f * time_f as time_f_sq
        FROM C1
    )
    GROUP BY segment_id
) 
GROUP BY c1.time, c1.segment_id
```

now that I run it:

```
WITH fake_data(event_ts, _engine_temperature_1) as (
    select * from values
    (current_timestamp, 50.0),
    (current_timestamp, 100.0),
    (current_timestamp, 150.0)
),c1 AS (
    SELECT
        event_ts AS time,
        _engine_temperature_1 AS engine_temperature_1,
        FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY event_ts) - 1) / 100) + 1 AS segment_id
    FROM fake_data
), c2 as (
    SELECT
        segment_id,
        engine_temperature_1 - AVG(engine_temperature_1) AS x,
        engine_temperature_1,
        time,
        time * time as time_sq,
        time::float as time_f,
        time_f * time_f as time_f_sq
    FROM C1
), c3 as (
    SELECT 
        segment_id,
        SUM(x) / COUNT(*) AS a,
        SUM(x * time) / SUM(time_sq) AS b,
        AVG(engine_temperature_1) - (SUM(x * time_f_sq) / SUM(time_f_sq)) - (SUM(x * time_f) / SUM(time_f_sq)) AS c
    FROM c2
    GROUP BY segment_id
)
SELECT 
    c1.time,
    c1.segment_id,
    AVG(C1.engine_temperature_1) AS avg_temp,
    AVG(C1.engine_temperature_1) - (a * POWER(AVG(c1.time), 2) + b * AVG(c1.time) + c) AS residual
FROM C1
CROSS JOIN c3 
GROUP BY c1.time, c1.segment_id
```

it begs the question what is time_ts unit? because time does not normally be squared.

ok, so if I change to just int's for time, and just make more data that makes sense, and comment out that final maths part, because Snowflake is correct "it just makes no sense"

```
WITH fake_data(time, engine_temperature_1, segment_id) as (
    select *  from values
    (10, 50.0, 0),
    (13, 100.0, 0),
    (15, 150.0, 0),
    (111, 51.0, 1),
    (114, 101.0, 1),
    (116, 151.0, 1)
),c1 AS (
    select * from fake_data
    --SELECT
    --    event_ts AS time,
    --    _engine_temperature_1 AS engine_temperature_1,
    --    FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY event_ts) - 1) / 100) + 1 AS segment_id
    --FROM fake_data
), c2 as (
    SELECT
        segment_id,
        engine_temperature_1 - AVG(engine_temperature_1) over(partition by segment_id) AS x,
        engine_temperature_1,
        time,
        time * time as time_sq,
        time::float as time_f,
        time_f * time_f as time_f_sq
    FROM C1
), c3 as (
    SELECT 
        segment_id,
        SUM(x) / COUNT(*) AS a,
        SUM(x * time) / SUM(time_sq) AS b,
        AVG(engine_temperature_1) - (SUM(x * time_f_sq) / SUM(time_f_sq)) - (SUM(x * time_f) / SUM(time_f_sq)) AS c
    FROM c2
    GROUP BY segment_id
)
SELECT 
    c1.time,
    c1.segment_id,
    *
    --AVG(C1.engine_temperature_1) AS avg_temp,
   --avg_temp - (c3.a * POWER(AVG(c1.time), 2) + c3.b * AVG(c1.time) + c3.c) AS residual
FROM C1
CROSS JOIN c3 
--GROUP BY c1.time, c1.segment_id
```

gives:

[image]

which makes me think you shouldn't be doing a cross join, but still what you really are wanting/expecting is missing, and guess the gaps is too hard.

Comment: interestingly, the AVG used in define X is not grouped across anything, so your X is not the deviation I assume you are looking for, which implies `X` will always be zero.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help. In those lines, I received those errors:

engine_temperature_1 - AVG(engine_temperature_1) AS x,
time * time as time_sq,
time::float as time_f,
time_f * time_f as time_f_sq 

)

syntax error line 43 at position 33 unexpected '-'.
syntax error line 46 at position 17 unexpected '*'.
syntax error line 47 at position 16 unexpected '::'.
syntax error line 48 at position 19 unexpected '*'.
syntax error line 52 at position 0 unexpected ')'. (line 40)

Comment: So could you please help me in how to fix this in query so we can take an average if the X has only a value?

Comment: I got this error in line 'time * time as time_sq,'  c2 table: 

Invalid argument types for function '*': (TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9), TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9))

Comment: yes, your code is just very broken, and guessing safe meanings for things you have written is rather painful.

Comment: TABLE1 contains timeseries data (1 HZ data). I tried what you suggested  and got the error:

Invalid argument types for function '*': (TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9), TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9))

Comment: Your code works file if I am working with 'time' , not datetime column. if I am working with datetime what should change in the query?

Comment: event_ts is the table is a datetime column, not time in seconds.

Comment: a timestamp/time is single point value. thus squaring it has no meaning. The distance between two times, that is a vector, now that has the ability to be squared.